How to remove AutoFilter from Excel file with Apache POI library?
I have an xlsx file with Autofilter inside. Does exist any possibilty to remove it with Apache POI library? sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress) just creates it, but does not remove.

No, there is not a method to remove auto-filter from a  worksheet using Apache POI up to now. And it is not simple, as creating the auto-filter also creates hidden named ranges, winch also need to be removed then. For XSSF it might be achievable to me, but not for HSSF. But maybe this is a XY-problem? Why do you need to remove auto-filter from a  worksheet?

For XSSF (Office Open XML *.xlsx file format) it is as simple as:
... void removeAutoFilter(XSSFSheet sheet) {
 if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter() != null) {
  sheet.getCTWorksheet().unsetAutoFilter();
 }
}

That is: If the underlying CTWorksheet contains AutoFilter then unset that. No need to remove the hidden named range _xlnm._FilterDatabase from each sheet as Excel itself does not so if sheet-auto-filter gets unset. It stays there and waits for new setting the sheet-auto-filter which only updates the refers-to then.
Complete example which unset sheet-auto-filter from each sheet.
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class RemoveAutoFilter{
    
 static void removeAutoFilter(XSSFSheet sheet) {
  if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter() != null) {
   sheet.getCTWorksheet().unsetAutoFilter();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("./ExcelSource.xlsx")); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelResult.xlsx") ) {
   for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {   
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
    removeAutoFilter(sheet);
   }
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}


Many thanks, It works
